# SQL - update field based on count of other field in row in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table [applicants] with the following fields:

1) MemberID
2) Attempts

Some of my attempts are NULL.

I would like to update the attempts field to 0 for those rows where the MemberID count in the table is 1.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE applicants
SET Attempts = 0
WHERE MemberID IN
     (SELECT MemberID FROM applicants GROUP BY MemberID HAVING COUNT(MemberID)=1)
  AND Attempts IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But why do you group by MemberID?

Comment: `GROUP BY MemberID HAVING COUNT(MemberID)=1` allows to get that `MemberID`-s which count in group is equals to one.

Answer (score 1):

general approach would be

```
update applicants set
    Attempts = 0
where
    MemberID in (select t.MemberID from applicants as t group by t.MemberID having count(*) = 1) and 
    Attempts is null -- if you need it
```

in sql server you can do something like:

```
with cte as (
    select *, count(*) over(partition by MemberID) as cnt
    from applicants
)
update cte set
   Attempts = 0
where cnt = 1 and Attempts is null
```